# Simple Input Restriction Issues

Tags: java

I have a program, first I need to enter the command - help, and why choose from 2 commands - exp or sum and so on. At first, help should always be entered, but I can not enter help, but I can enter exp or sum immediately, how do I make a notification so that if I enter exp or sum, the console wrote to me: enter the help command first

My code:

```
import utils.Calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Never {

    public static final String STOP = "-stop";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter command: for the initial operation of the program, type "help");
        String word = scan.nextLine(); 

        while (!word.equals(STOP)) {  
            switch (word) {

                case "help": {
                    System.out.println("exp - outputs the root of a number");
                    System.out.println("sum - displays the sum of two numbers");
                }
                break;
                case "exp": {
                    long result = Calculator.exp(scan.nextInt()); 
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
                break;
                case "sum": {
                    System.out.println("Enter first number");
                    int first = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number");
                    int second = scan.nextInt();


                    long result = Calculator.sum(first, second);


                    System.out.println(result);

                }
                break;
                default: {
                    System.out.println("Now exit programm");
                }

            }

            word = scan.nextLine(); 

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How is this related to Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `do-while` loop before your first `while` loop:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String word;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter command: for the initial operation of the program, type "help");
    word = scan.nextLine(); 
} while(!word.equals("help"));

// the rest of the code
```

That way the program checks so many times until the user types in help

Comment: And why do we use do while, you can write information, otherwise I'm new

Comment: @Mike we use `do-while` to avoid duplication of code. Because with a simple while loop we need to check the condition first. So we have `word = scan.nextLine(); ` outside of the loop. When the input is wrong, we then would enter the `while` and get again the input from the user via `word = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: @Mike glad i could help